# How to animate view height within UIScrollView using autolayout?

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

A `UIScrollView` contains three subviews: `UIView1`, `UIView2` and `UIView3`.

[image]

The height of `UIView1` and `UIView3` is defined by the content of these views using autolayout constraints.

The height of `UIView2` is also defined by its subviews. However it should be possible to **toggle the visibility of `UIView2`**.

When `Button` is pressed `UIView2` should collaps to a height of 0 (animated). When `Button` is pressed again `UIView2` should be animated back to its original height.

**How can I do this (in Objsctiv-C)?**

If the height of `UIView2` would be fixed it would be no problem to animated the height-consraint from 0 to a fixed value (e.g. 100) or vice versa. But since the height is not fixed but depending on the subviews I do not know the exact height of `UIView2`. **How to solve this?**

Answer (score 1):

Create two constraints one for height and other for top space like following in you .h file

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *view2HeightConstraint;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *view2TopSpaceFromView1;
```

Create action like below, in you .m file

```
- (IBAction)toggleButtonTapped:(id)sender {
UIButton *btn =  (UIButton *)sender;
if ([btn isSelected])
{
    [btn setSelected:false];
    _view2HeightConstraint.constant = 45.0;
    _view2TopSpaceFromView1.constant = 8.0;

}
else{
    [btn setSelected:true];
    _view2HeightConstraint.constant = 0.0;
    _view2TopSpaceFromView1.constant = 0.0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create 2 constraints

1- View2 height constraint = 0 => priority = 999

2- SubView3 bottom constraint to View2 => priority = 1000

when you want to hide Views 2 toggle the priority and animate

Answer (score 0):

A simple and straightforward solution to this would be to contain your *UIView1*, *UIView2* and *UIView3* inside a **UIStackView**.

Then, you can set the **hidden** property of either of these 3 views directly inside the *UIView* animation block to animate the appearance of any of these views.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    self.secondView.hidden = YES;
}];
```

Reference: [UIStackView Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview?language=objc)